# How to write PNG file in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I get the content of my png file by converting this file and I want to write it in my D drive. Its my code :

```
s = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());

File.WriteAllText(@"D:\result.png", s);
```

but the result is not same with the selected file (.png) and when I write it, it be damaged.
I also used ASCII Encoding and UTF, but nothing changed...

any idea?
Thanks

Comment: A PNG file is not a text file so you can't read it in like this.

Comment: so how can I do that? I want to add some bytes at the end of my file and write it. how can I do that?

Comment: What data are you wanting to add to the file? Sounds like there is likely a better way to achieve this.

Comment: Normally, when I'm working with an image in C#, I'm using the `[Bitmap Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)` and keeping the data as [streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) in between the file and the Bitmap object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Read All Bytes
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());

//Data that needs to added, converted to bytes, Better off making a function for this
String str = "Data to be added";
byte[] newBytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, newBytes, 0, newBytes.Length);

//Add the two byte arrays, the file bytes, the new data bytes
byte[] fileBytesWithAddedData = new byte[ fileBytes.Length + newBytes.Length ];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(fileBytes, 0, fileBytesWithAddedData, 0, fileBytes.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy( newBytes, 0, fileBytesWithAddedData, fileBytes.Length, newBytes.Length );

//Write to new file
File.WriteAllBytes(@"D:\result.png", fileBytesWithAddedData);
```

Comment: While this is correct, it's a bit crazy to be doing in the first place. Exactly why I have not posted a similar answer. Just because you CAN do something, doesn't mean you SHOULD do it.

Comment: @DavidG: `Steganography` is a place where things like this are required. Please do not assume that you know always whether there is a requirement that is valid or not.

Comment: There's an assumption here that there is only appending, and not any manipulation of existing bytes.

Comment: @Christopher: The OP clearly says `I want to add some bytes at the end of my file and write it.`

Comment: `WriteAllText` still? And I might use two writes rather than a reallocate.

Comment: @DavidG why its crazy way?

Comment: @Elahe You are still to give a reason why you are doing this. Appending bytes to binary files can often break them. I don't really know about PNG file structure, so it may work, but I am betting there is a better way to achieve your goal here.

Comment: @Abhi You'd add steganography to the uncompressed image data and read and write it using the System.Drawing classes rather than tinkering with the compressed bitstream directly. (Unless there are  unused bits in the compression, but I'd be very surprised.)

Comment: @Rup: Are you saying adding bytes to the end of a `png` file will not work?

Comment: @DavidG I want to add a code, at the end of my file and when my project want to display it, will check the file. if the end of my file is same with my code, it will display... for security purpose

Comment: The code? I think you meant `WriteAllBytes` on the last line. Oh, I see: I hadn't though of appending bytes to the end of a file as steganography: I suppose it is. Typically when people say steganography and images they mean weaving the message into the picture itself.

Answer (score 3):

PNG is binary data, not text. You need to read all *bytes* and write those.

It does seem though you're just looking for [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx).

To read all bytes, use the conveniently named method [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.

Comment: No, I dont want to copy exactly. I want to add some bytes to it

Comment: @Elahe Adding bytes to a PNG would likely break the file.

Comment: I tested it by Free Hex Editor Neo. I added some bytes at the end of file and saved it. It worked and didnt damage