# Why does converting a PNG file to ASCII string and writing those bytes to a file not work in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization, ascii, endianness

This is not the same question as *[How to write PNG file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097800/how-to-write-png-file-in-c-sharp)*

I am reading a file using ReadAllBytes(), adding some strings around the file (it sounds silly, but eventually I'll use these strings as headers for purposes of be transmitted serially).

However, my problem is that when I read the data as an ASCII string on the other end (the end that will be receiving this serial data eventually), I get slightly different data than the original bytes, which means when I write this to a PNG file, only 90% of the data is correct, meaning the whole file is unusable. I understand that ASCII and binary are not the same, but ASCII is 8 bits long, and since there is an ASCII value for all values from 0 through 255, why would this not be equivalent to just writing bytes to a file regardless of if the file type is PNG?

```
// Reading the data from a file
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\tinytest.png";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
byte[] footer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(footerString);
byte[] fileAndFooter = new byte[file.Length + footer.Length];
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(file, 0, fileAndFooter, 0, file.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(footer, 0, fileAndFooter, file.Length, footer.Length);

// Writing the data to a file after reading its ASCII interpretation
// (why isn't this the same as reading the bytes?)
string fandf = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileAndFooter);
int index = fandf.IndexOf(footerString);
string fileWithoutFooter = fandf.Substring(0, index);
ByteArrayToFile("dummyfilestrightthrough", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileWithoutFooter));
```

HexDump Original file

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52
00 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 08 06 00 00 00 1F F3 FF
61 00 00 02 F5 49 44 41 54 78 DA 7D 93 59 48 94
51 14 C7 FF 77 BE 99 D1 C9 5D 49 CB CA 34 6D D4
34 97 32 C1 4A C5 32 0C 31 C3 52 7B B2 2C 8A C4
C2 30 8B 40 0C 5A 90 A2 87 0C 2C 21 83 30 C1 A8
84 22 A5 D4 CA 25 5B 50 51 C7 46 1D 1B 25 17 54
5C 98 D1 74 9C ED DB A6 CF 87 C6 34 EB 5C EE C3
B9 9C FB E3 70 EF EF 10 AC 88 C4 EA B0 A8 10 B7
F0 1C B9 8B D7 21 31 E1 44 66 9E 23 53 FA D9 DE
1E ED 8F A2 67 07 DF 57 AC AC 27 7F 26 69 6F E3
EE 9C 0F C9 BC EC E7 E0 04 3D 37 0E 03 B3 00 DA
C2 82 22 F6 D0 D2 0C 6A 87 14 AA B6 11 45 F8 E7
0C 15 FD 17 20 E5 75 F4 D5 9B 51 97 6E D8 49 A6
30 4B 8F 83 E7 29 70 C2 B9 91 67 61 64 CD 10 11
0A 44 64 8F A7 CA 4F CA B2 C4 9A D0 65 80 98 F2
E0 DD D9 11 A7 BF 44 7A 3A 63 DA 30 04 19 25 83
45 58 34 CF C1 CC 33 C2 E6 60 62 79 10 8A 60 5A
4F A3 BC B5 F1 6C 63 66 7B A9 15 70 B2 EA 48 75
76 64 42 92 C6 D4 01 27 A9 3B D6 50 CE 20 44 04
46 B8 C8 58 78 01 C4 42 C7 18 30 CF CD C1 22 A6
F0 BA AD 7B E0 45 5A 83 DC 0A C8 6B 3C 36 1C 23
77 DC 0C 8E 05 2F B4 4B A4 0B 60 69 5B B0 1C 81
89 A3 61 14 19 21 E2 1C 20 95 38 41 43 8D A2 A9
73 02 6F 8E 2A 89 15 90 FF F5 F8 A0 83 72 9D 8F
BB 24 10 C9 29 C9 A8 EE BC 0D D6 B7 19 C6 05 31
CC A2 05 78 8A A2 91 E0 71 1D 55 AF AA F0 B8 A2
04 6E 59 16 54 A5 B7 2F 01 B2 DF 1D 1D 31 D7 B3
5E 3A 95 1B 4E 64 A5 E3 D1 83 4A 04 9D 19 81 6B
B0 0E 52 66 3D 98 DA 78 F8 FB FB E1 49 69 05 BA
07 5B E0 99 6B 8F FA 53 8A 25 C0 E1 67 FB 9F EF
74 5D 9B 5E 99 A3 16 1E D0 09 33 93 73 D8 9A 4A
10 5F 68 83 C9 16 7B 74 5C 93 41 CF CC E1 E7 E8
2C 7C CE 51 30 C9 2D AA A6 8C AE 20 2B 60 D7 AD
88 BD 09 09 F2 4F 33 93 6A 28 1E D2 60 0D C0 EE
2B 76 70 D9 24 86 C1 48 A3 B5 D8 08 9D 1A D8 90
4A C1 71 8F 04 BD 75 A6 9C AE 82 EE 62 2B C0 BF
40 2E 0B F0 F2 AD 09 3F 40 62 B5 FA 09 C8 88 2D
0C E0 97 19 67 34 09 B9 1D C1 70 3B 8D 49 25 17
D6 7B A7 FB DB 32 91 82 F2 43 A2 63 E3 FD 9A CD
0E C3 20 AC 18 ED CD 7A 6C D9 67 83 C1 06 33 22
62 EC A0 13 3C 58 FC D2 FE 3A FA 4D 4F 61 4F D2
AA 2A C7 DF DD FF D2 2F 06 29 1A 83 66 A5 F2 E0
65 14 46 5B 04 1F 06 79 EF EF 45 3D 23 AB 02 02
F2 02 5D 83 C2 7C C7 A4 DB B4 B2 BE 0F F3 D6 02
1F A1 13 CD 30 87 A9 8F CC 45 F5 7D 55 D1 3F 87
69 31 B6 E7 ED 08 F3 0E 75 55 B0 81 33 82 50 04
BC 05 98 1F 60 A0 6D 66 EE A9 8B FB 72 FF 3B 8D
BF 23 F8 42 F8 46 38 D2 E5 12 0F C4 31 F3 98 A1
C7 90 D7 5F D2 5B B6 5A ED 2F 9C 0B 4A 20 5E 66
25 3B 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
```

HexDump "Received" file

```
3F 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52
00 00 00 10 00 00 00 10 08 06 00 00 00 1F 3F 3F
61 00 00 02 3F 49 44 41 54 78 3F 7D 3F 59 48 3F
51 14 3F 3F 77 3F 3F 3F 3F 5D 49 3F 3F 34 6D 3F
34 3F 32 3F 4A 3F 32 0C 31 3F 52 7B 3F 2C 3F 3F
3F 30 3F 40 0C 5A 3F 3F 3F 0C 2C 21 3F 30 3F 3F
3F 22 3F 3F 3F 25 5B 50 51 3F 46 1D 1B 25 17 54
5C 3F 3F 74 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 34 3F 5C 3F 3F
3F 3F 3F 3F 70 3F 3F 10 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 10 3F
3F 1C 3F 3F 3F 21 31 3F 44 66 3F 23 53 3F 3F 3F
1E 3F 3F 3F 67 07 3F 57 3F 3F 27 7F 26 69 6F 3F
3F 3F 0F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 04 3D 37 0E 03 3F 00 3F
3F 3F 22 3F 3F 3F 0C 6A 3F 14 3F 3F 11 45 3F 3F
0C 15 3F 17 20 3F 75 3F 3F 3F 51 3F 6E 3F 49 3F
30 4B 3F 3F 3F 29 70 3F 3F 3F 67 61 64 3F 10 11
0A 44 64 3F 3F 3F 4F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 65 3F 3F 3F
3F 3F 3F 11 3F 3F 44 7A 3A 63 3F 30 04 19 25 3F
45 58 34 3F 3F 3F 33 3F 3F 60 62 79 10 3F 60 5A
4F 3F 3F 3F 3F 6C 63 66 7B 3F 15 70 3F 3F 48 75
76 64 42 3F 3F 3F 01 27 3F 3B 3F 50 3F 20 44 04
46 3F 3F 58 78 01 3F 42 3F 18 30 3F 3F 3F 22 3F
3F 3F 3F 7B 3F 45 5A 3F 3F 0A 3F 6B 3C 36 1C 23
77 3F 0C 3F 05 2F 3F 4B 3F 0B 60 69 5B 3F 1C 3F
3F 3F 61 14 19 21 3F 1C 20 3F 38 41 43 3F 3F 3F
73 02 6F 3F 2A 3F 15 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 72 3F 3F
3F 24 10 3F 29 3F 3F 3F 3F 0D 3F 3F 19 3F 05 31
3F 3F 05 78 3F 3F 3F 3F 71 1D 55 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F
04 6E 59 16 54 3F 3F 2F 01 3F 3F 1D 1D 31 3F 3F
5E 3A 3F 1B 4E 64 3F 3F 3F 3F 4A 04 3F 19 3F 6B
3F 0E 52 66 3D 3F 3F 78 3F 3F 3F 3F 49 69 05 3F
07 5B 3F 3F 6B 3F 3F 53 3F 25 3F 3F 67 3F 3F 3F
74 5D 3F 5E 3F 3F 16 1E 3F 09 33 3F 73 3F 3F 4A
10 5F 68 3F 3F 16 7B 74 5C 3F 41 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F
2C 7C 3F 51 30 3F 2D 3F 3F 3F 3F 20 2B 60 3F 3F
3F 3F 09 09 3F 4F 33 3F 6A 28 1E 3F 60 0D 3F 3F
2B 76 70 3F 24 3F 3F 48 3F 3F 3F 08 3F 1A 3F 3F
4A 3F 71 3F 04 3F 75 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 62 2B 3F 3F
40 2E 0B 3F 3F 3F 09 3F 40 62 3F 3F 09 3F 3F 2D
0C 3F 3F 19 67 34 09 3F 1D 3F 70 3B 3F 49 25 17
3F 7B 3F 3F 3F 32 3F 3F 3F 43 3F 63 3F 3F 3F 3F
0E 3F 20 3F 18 3F 3F 7A 6C 3F 67 3F 3F 06 33 22
62 3F 3F 13 3C 58 3F 3F 3F 3A 3F 4D 4F 61 4F 3F
3F 2A 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 2F 06 29 1A 3F 66 3F 3F 3F
65 14 46 5B 04 1F 06 79 3F 3F 45 3D 23 3F 02 02
3F 02 5D 3F 3F 7C 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 3F 0F 3F 3F 02
1F 3F 13 3F 30 3F 3F 3F 3F 45 3F 7D 55 3F 3F 3F
69 31 3F 3F 3F 08 3F 0E 75 55 3F 3F 33 3F 50 04
3F 05 3F 1F 60 3F 6D 66 3F 3F 3F 3F 72 3F 3B 3F
3F 23 3F 42 3F 46 38 3F 3F 12 0F 3F 31 3F 3F 3F
3F 3F 3F 5F 3F 5B 3F 5A 3F 2F 3F 0B 4A 20 5E 66
25 3B 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 3F 42 60 3F
```

Comment: ASCII is actually 7 bits long. [The absolute minimum every software developer must absolutely, positively must know about Unicode and character sets](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: @JohnWu is that what my problem is?

Comment: Probably. For this sort of requirement, I suggest you either (1) store the whole thing as UTF8-encoded XML, with the image as a CDATA section, or (2) store and transmit the metadata separately, e.g. in headers.

Comment: Encoding.ASCII produces '?' for any byte outside of the range [0..0x7F].  Which is 0x3F in hex, you'll have no trouble seeing those back.  Base64 encoding is one of the standard ways to encode binary data to text that is likely to survive transmission, Convert.ToBase64String().

Comment: @Goku what are you trying to do and what do you mean by text and ASCII? Why should you send *text* instead of the file itself? If you really need to send the image as 7-bit US-ASCII, use [Conver.ToBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=netframework-4.8) to create a [BASE64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding of the binary data. BAE64 is used in MIME encoding, embedding images in image URLs, etc

Comment: Are you trying to create a `data:image/png;` url perhaps?

Comment: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @HansPassant, I think that answers my question. Would you post an answer so I can accept it. Could you also elaborate on what you mean by "likely to survive transmission"?

Comment: _"This is not the same question as [How to write PNG file in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26097800)"_ -- actually, it pretty much is. You have the same exact misunderstanding about the difference between binary and ASCII data as exhibited by the person who asked that question, and the answer is the same: don't treat your binary data as ASCII. The code you have to write the data is fine as far as it goes, but you have to make sure you recover the data in the _exact_ inverse of the creation of the data (in addition to of course doing everything correctly). ...

Comment: ... That means that you need to determine the footer bytes independently, use the length of those bytes to identify all the non-footer bytes, and recover the non-footer bytes _as bytes_. Converting to text means you are reinterpreting the bytes as something that they are not, and so of course you wind up with something completely different from what you started with.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you treated a binary value as an ASCII code.

```
// This is wrong

string fandf = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileAndFooter);
```

You could just store the string plus the size first and the receiver will read size of string/footer then read the string convert it to ASCII then read the PNG bytes.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\Andy\Desktop\tinytest.png";
byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
byte[] footer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(footerString);
byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(footer.Length);
byte[] fileAndFooter = new byte[file.Length + footer.Length+lengthBytes.Length];

System.Buffer.BlockCopy(lengthBytes, 0, filteAndFooter, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(footer, 0, fileAndFooter, lengthBytes.Length, footer.Length);
System.Buffer.BlockCopy(file, 0, fileAndFooter, footer.Length+lengthBytes.Length, file.Length);
```

Comment: what do you mean by this? "you could just store the string plus the size first and the receiver will read size of string/footer then read the string convert it to ascii then read the png bytes"